# asp gridview hyperlink call javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the result of dropdownlist but if set `visible= 'false'` the hyperlink function of the gridview will not work anymore.
I have a dropdownlist containing three options each time it changes it needs to redirect the hyperlink:

1. PASTA
2. Source
3. Brand

I can receive the result while clicking the hyperlink of gridview, only if keeping the textbox visible to 'true'.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="stock" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  Width="15%"/>
 <asp:TextBox ID="lblstock" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

The gridview hyperlink below only work it if dropdownlist doesn't change:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FOOD_NO")%>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("javascript:openWindow(""../FOOD/FOOD_STG.aspx?FOOD_NO={0}"")", Eval("FOOD_NO"))%>' />
<asp:Label ID="FOOD_NO" runat="server" Visible="False" Text='<%# Bind("FOOD_NO") %>' />
```

JavaScript:

```
  function openWindow() {

        var result = document.getElementById("lblstock").value.strURL;
        var url = "";
        if (result != "")
        {
            switch (result) {
                case "PASTA":
                    url = "../FOOD_Rep/FOOD_Rep.aspx?FOOD_NO={0}";
                 break;

                case "Source":
                    url = "../FOOD_Ing/FOOD_Ing.aspx?FOOD_NO={0}";
                break;

                case "Brand":
                    url = "../FOOD_Brd/FOOD_Brd.aspx?FOOD_NO={0}";
                break;

            }
            var winopen = window.open(url + "&FOOD_ID=" + $("#GROUP_ID").val(), 'Memo', ' left=50, screenx= 10, width=1360,height=820,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,toolbar=0');
            winopen.focus();

        }
```

vb code behind:

```
lblstock.Text = stock.SelectedValue
```

I have been stuck here for sometimes please help thank you.

Comment: It's not clear how the dropdownlist is related to the problem? It doesn't get mentioned in any of the script code. Can you describe what the actual requirements are here (in the abstract, without reference to specific page controls)? It feels like you are making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be, but I can't be sure because it's not really obvious what is supposed to happen.

Comment: @ADyson i need to change the hyperlink  from first column of the gridview  no matter how many data inside the gridview, i need to change the hyperlink redirect address when the dropdownlist is change the javascript code have list the switch case that will be change.

Comment: ok. So then why are you trying to take the value from the textbox instead of the dropdownlist? That will only be populated when there's a postback. And it seems an unnecessary intermediate step. In any case `value.strURL` almost certainly doesn't exist, unless you somehow populated your textbox with a JSON object??? Also, why are you ignoring the URL that you pass to the "openWindow" function? You pass the correct URL to it as a parameter, but then the openWindow function does not receive it and tries to invent a URL based on something else that doesn't exist.

Comment: also `document.getElementById("lblstock")` will not return anything because there can be multiple elements with ID lblStock (since there can be multiple GridView rows), therefore .NET will give it a different ID on the client.

Comment: is the "AutoPostBack=true" necessary for the DropDownList, other than to populate the hidden textbox? i.e. does it do anything else on that postback except run `lblstock.Text = stock.SelectedValue`? If not, we can remove it and that will help. If you tell me that information, I might be able to make a better solution.

Comment: P.S. Can you use jQuery in your project? It would be much easier if you can.

Comment: @ADyson yes i can use Jquery in my project, but i not good at Jquery.

Comment: You might not be, but I'm alright at it... Can you answer my question above regarding the AutoPostBack as well, please?

Comment: @ADyson AutoPostBack is for triggle DB Query when user select

Comment: ok so we can't get rid of the autopostback then. If it all did was populate the textbox, then we could remove it. But if a query runs as well that's different. In that case I think the best thing to do is to handle the click event on the hyperlink and work out the correct URL at that moment. Give me some time and I will try to write something that should work.

Comment: @ADyson thank you very much

Comment: can I just check, is the "stock" dropdownlist within the gridview row? I.e. is it repeated multiple times, or is there only one instance of this dropdown in the page?

Comment: @ADyson no, dropdownlist is refer to another db query when the page is load.
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN PASTA IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PASTA
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SOURCE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SOURCE 
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN BrandIS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Brand
FROM FOOD_INGREDIANT
it will help to count how many item will have and append to the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to test this for obvious reasons, but this should work: When the hyperlink it clicked, it will read the currently selected value from the DropDownList and use that to create the URL.

This is assuming that the possible selectable values in the Dropdownlist are "PASTA", "Source" and "Brand", as indicated in the original javascript function that you posted.

It uses jQuery, simply because the syntax is cleaner for creating event handlers, etc. But you could easily re-write it using native JavaScript if you wanted to.

*DropDownList:*

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="stock" CssClass="stock-dropdown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  Width="15%"/>
```

*Hyperlink:*

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" CssClass="stock-hyperlink" Text='<%# Eval("FOOD_NO")%>' data-foodno='<%# Eval("FOOD_NO")%>' NavigateUrl="#"' />
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(function() {
    $(".stock-hyperlink").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //stop normal link behaviour

        var stockVal = $(".stock-dropdown").val(); //get the selected value of the dropdown
        var url = "";

        if (stockVal != "")
        {
            switch(stockVal)
            {
                case "PASTA":
                    url = "../FOOD_Rep/FOOD_Rep";
                    break;
                case "Source":
                    url = "../FOOD_Ing/FOOD_Ing";
                    break;
                case "Brand":
                    url = "../FOOD_Brd/FOOD_Brd";
                    break;
            }
            url += ".aspx?FOOD_NO=" + $(this).data("foodno") + "&FOOD_ID=" + $("#GROUP_ID").val();

            var winopen = window.open(url, 'Memo', ' left=50, screenx= 10, width=1360,height=820,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,toolbar=0');
            winopen.focus();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: it might no be the way, but still help on my project thank you so much.